# Problema para visualizar mi proyecto en Github

Tags: git, github

Tengo un problema, segui los pasos para cargar mi pagina web html, css y js en github. El problema es que mi pagina web, por algun motivo no se la visualiza. Busque en mil portales pero no encuentro la respuesta, volvi a eliminar todo y realizar los pasos indicados por otra persona (varias veces) y tengo el mismo problema. Alguna ayuda ?
Github
dormido95
dormido95.github.io

Comment: Acabo de acceder y puedo ver que tienes `Jekyll` instalado. ¿Dónde está el problema de la visualización? ¿Quizás es problema de caché de tu navegador? ¿Has intentado visualizar la página desde otro navegador y/o desde pestaña privada?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Al ingresar a mi repo e ingresar a la direccion dormido95.github.io, lo unico que visualizo es el archivo README.TXT! E intentado ingresar desde otro navegador.